# check if a row value is null in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql, isnull

I am using a custom function in pyspark to check a condition for each row in a spark dataframe and add columns if condition is true.

The code is as below:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

def customFunction(row):
    if (row.prod.isNull()):
        prod_1 = "new prod"
        return (row + Row(prod_1))
    else:
        prod_1 = row.prod
        return (row + Row(prod_1))

sdf = sdf_temp.map(customFunction)
sdf.show()
```

I get the error mention below:

**AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isNull'**

How can I check for null values for specific columns in the current row in my custom function?

Comment: Could you `show` your `Dataframe` or at least print its schema?

Comment: Schema of Dataframe is: root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- prod_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- prod: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 15):

Considering that `sdf` is a `DataFrame` you can use a `select` statement.

```py
sdf.select("*", when(col("pro").isNull(), lit("new pro")).otherwise(col("pro")))
```

Comment: But I need to do several operations on different columns of the dataframe, hence wanted to use a custom function. Why can I check for nulls in custom function?

Comment: You need to modify the question, and add your requirements.